# Return type based on type argument

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have this code, which type checks fine on its own:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple, Type

def df2objects(df: pd.DataFrame, object_type: Type[BaseObject]) -> Tuple[BaseObject, ...]:
    return tuple(object_type(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

But if I try to use it:

```
def use_it(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[DerivedObject,...]:
    return df2objects(df, DerivedObject)
```

I get

> Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[BaseObject, ...]", expected "Tuple[DerivedObject, ...]")mypy(error)

I can fix this with

```
import typing

def use_it(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[DerivedObject,...]:
    return typing.cast(Tuple[DerivedObject,...], df2objects(df, DerivedObject))
```

But what I would really like to do is specify that df2objects returns a Tuple of object_type, like this:

```
def df2objects(df: pd.DataFrame, object_type: Type[BaseObject]) -> Tuple[object_type, ...]:
```

or this:

```
def df2objects(df: pd.DataFrame, object_type: Type[BaseObject]) -> Tuple[BaseObject, ...]:
    return typing.cast(Tuple[object_type,...],tuple(object_type(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Of course, neither of those actually work.

Comment: You may be able to use [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was alluded to in the comments, using a `TypeVar` is the solution here, I believe. Assuming `DerivedObject` is a subclass of `BaseObject`, the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Tuple

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseObject)

def df2objects(df: pd.DataFrame, object_type: Type[T]) -> Tuple[T, ...]:
    return tuple(object_type(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict(orient='records')

def use_it(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[DerivedObject,...]:
    return df2objects(df, DerivedObject)
```

By using the `bound` keyword-argument, we restrict the possible types the `TypeVar` `T` could be to `DerivedObject` and its subclasses.

The mypy documentation on generic functions can be found [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-functions), the docs for `TypeVar` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), and information on bound `TypeVar`s can be found [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound).